# Expand row values in pandas into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns:id and vendor_name as given below:

```
 id   vendor_name
  1   vendor1
  1   vendor2
  2   vendor1
```

I want to transform it as follows:

```
 id   vendor_name1 vendor_name2
  1    vendor1        vendor2  
  2    vendor1        nan
```

Is there a way i can acheive this in pandas?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape with new columns names created by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1 = (df.set_index(['id', df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1)])['vendor_name']
        .unstack()
        .add_prefix('vendor_name')
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
   id vendor_name1 vendor_name2
0   1      vendor1      vendor2
1   2      vendor1          NaN
```